# Crear un backup de Postgres vía consola en Debian

Tags: postgresql, debian

Necesito sacar un backup de una base de datos mía vía consola / terminal (por motivos académicos) pero me saca estos errores, yo tengo Debian Jessie y psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.1.

[image: im1]

[image: im2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ejecutar `pg_dump` lo debes hacer fuera de la consola `psql`, es decir, ejecútalo directamente en tu terminal ya que es un comando como cualquier otro:

```
$ pg_dump -U prueba ripso_v1 -f miarchivosql.sql
```

Para más información puedes referirte a la documentación:

- [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: y para windows dónde la pongo? si la pongo en el cmd no reconoce el pg_dump

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez si no me equivoco, tienes que entrar a la carpeta en donde se ha instalado el PostgreSQL y ubicarte en la carpeta `bin`, imagino que la otra opción es que agregues el comando en el `PATH` de Windows para que lo pudas ejecutar de manera global

Answer (score 1):

Para *Windows* debes de definir como variables de entorno la carpeta de *PostgreSQL*. Después debes ejecutar el *CMD* y escribir estos comandos:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f "E:/prueba.sql" name_basedatos
```

... y listo, ya con eso creará una copia y para restablecerá la copia. Es igual, creas la base de datos y después ejecutar estos comandos en *CMD*:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f "E:/prueba.sql" nombre_basedatos
```